# Pil/Pillow doesn't support PNG files - Kivy Buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, python-imaging-library, buildozer

Pillow works with jpeg and most image file types but not PNG.

I did run `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated

**ERROR:**

```
03-14 01:55:24.934 21254 25588 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 4088, in photo_effect
03-14 01:55:24.934 21254 25588 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/picapp/PIL/ImageEnhance.py", line 54, in __init__
03-14 01:55:24.934 21254 25588 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/picapp/PIL/Image.py", line 892, in convert
03-14 01:55:24.934 21254 25588 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/PicApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/picapp/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 210, in load
03-14 01:55:24.934 21254 25588 I python  :  IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: If only png files not been supported, please consider reinstall `libpng`.

Comment: @YangHG `libpng12-dev` is already installed

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I think `libpng` is different than `libpng12`. I've checked my CentOS system, and I found some different libpng files: `libpng.so.3.50.0`, `libpng12.so.0.50.0`, `libpng15.so.15.13.0`. Can you please try install `libpng-1.5.13`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still not working... I even tried it with libpng16-dev, also I'm using ubuntu 16.04... I think it's because buildozer installs a different version when compiling even though the system already has libpng installed (I'm still learning)